# Filling out graduate school recommendation letter rubrics for students

Tags: graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter, professorship

A question for other professors or recommenders out there.

1. How do you deal with filling out these complicated rubrics that some schools have on their recommendation letters for graduate applications, especially if you have to recommend a large number of students? I'm talking about the "the student is in the (x) percent" or the "the student's research potential is in the (y) percent". I confess that my default is to not treat these questions very seriously, and select top or second from the top for students I want to get into a given program. If I think a student has overstepped, I sometimes rank them lower.
2. On the other side of things, are these actually used at a departmental level? My field is math and I would suspect that there is a threshold that would disqualify a person from being accepted, but the numbers are otherwise useless as a fine measure of applicant's quality.

Thankfully, many schools have gotten rid of these obnoxious questions and just ask for a letter, but a few do remain.